# Contact Not Found Exception thrown with valid contact IDs

Tags: xdb, mongodb, experience-profile

In the following code...

```
var contactManager = GetContactManager();
var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
if (contact == null)
{
    Log.Info("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.ExperienceProfileController.GetAdditionalInfo: Contact not found!: " + contactId.ToString(), this);
    throw new ContactNotFoundException();
}
```

... contact is apparently `null` because the ContactNotFoundException is being thrown.

The odd thing is that the contact DOES appear to exist.   For example, passing a `contactId` of `f5a28b73-f58b-44f2-a011-4d76bb4984c9` (or any other GUID) results in this error being thrown.

But when I execute the following in the MongoDB...

`db.getCollection('Contacts').find({"_id" : NUUID("f5a28b73-f58b-44f2-a011-4d76bb4984c9")})`

... I get back a valid result, with visits, etc.:

[image]

This code worked fine with 8.1 Update 2/xDB 1.0, but does not work with 8.2 Update 2/xDB 2.0.

Does anyone have any ideas why this behavior would be occurring and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the implementation of `GetContactManager`, I can't say what is wrong exactly, but it is most likely the way you're creating the contact manager object.

Here's the correct way of creating it:

```
ContactManager manager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
```

Anyway, the easiest way of achieving what you want is using the `ContactRepository` instead:

```
var contactRepository = (ContactRepositoryBase)Factory.CreateObject("contactRepository", true);
var contact = contactRepository.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
```